# Default generated values (Short Url) changes after refreshing mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, default, dynamically-generated

I'm using [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) package to shorten my URLs.

Currently, user have this kind of url: https://bucard.co.il/digitalCard/5edd4112eb6ba017d8a4595c (the long string is the _id),
and I want to make it like this: https://bucard.co.il/digitalCard/Y2i1_53Vc

So, I added ShortID field, and as in the documantion, I did this in *models/VisitCard.js*:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const shortid = require('shortid');

const VisitCardsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ShortID: {
        type: String,
        default: shortid.generate
    },
    ....
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('VisitCards', VisitCardsSchema);
```

And my get request in *routes/VisitCard.js*:

```
// Get a specific visit card
router.get('/:visitCardId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let cardShortId = req.params.visitCardId;

    let allVisitCards = await VisitCard.find({}); // That's how I saw that all the values changed after every get request.
    let visitCard = await VisitCard.findOne({ ShortID: cardShortId }); // Never found the card by the short id - even after coping the short id from above, after the next try it changes.

    if (!visitCard) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'Not existing card.'
      });
    } else {
        return res.status(200).json(visitCard);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(404).json({
      message: 'Some server issue accured...'
    });
  }
});
```

Now, the proplem is where after every refresh of the browser or another get request, all the ShortID's of all cards are changing (generated again). I want instead that the short url will not be refreshes after every restart of the server, and **it will be stored in the Database**.

How can I do that after each card gets it's shortID (by default) it will directlly be stored in the DB ?

By the way, I could just have that after every submits of visit card to put some random string to be stored with the other paramters, but I already have visit cards of users in my service.

**THANK YOU !!!**

Answer (score 0):

Tried reproducing your issue:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const shortid = require("shortid");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test9999", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", async function() {


    await mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
    // we're connected!

    console.log("Connected");

const VisitCardsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    ShortID: {
        type: String,
        default: shortid.generate
    }
});



    const VisitCard = mongoose.model("VisitCard", VisitCardsSchema);

    const v1 = new VisitCard({name: "abc"});
    const v2 = new VisitCard({name: "cde"});
    await v1.save();
    await v2.save();

    await VisitCard.find(function(err, vcs) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log(vcs);
    });
    
    console.log("VCS second call:");

    await VisitCard.find(function(err, vcs) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log(vcs);
    });

});
```

Apparently, it works perfectly fine. I even commented part with dropping db for a moment and values are persisted correctly.

The problem must be somewhere else - you sure you do not drop the db or the collection with each GET request somewhere else in the code?

This one: `await mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();` drops entire db, `mongooseconnection.connection.db.dropCollection` drops a collection. Check if you can find such lines somewhere in your code.